Spring Boot and JPA new related records are updating instead of inserting
I'm working on my first project with Spring Boot. I'm trying to use JPA to load and edit user and user_role tables in a MySQL database. Each user can have multiple roles.
I can query for an existing user with multiple roles, but saving a new user with one or more roles fails to save the role to the user_role table. Debug data shows the insert into user, followed by update statements to the user_role table.
The records being saved are new, so why isn't it inserting into user_role?
I've tried a variety of approaches, but the below code works the best so far (reads fine, no exceptions thrown). Nothing has worked for inserting new user_role records when saving a new user record.
Code:
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String rolename;
    private Long userId;
...
}

...
User user = new User(testUserName, testUserPassword1);
user.addUserRole("test");
user.addUserRole("user");
userRepository.save(user);
...

Debug output:
insert into user (password,username) values (?,?)
binding parameter (1:VARCHAR) <- [password]
binding parameter (2:VARCHAR) <- [Test User]
update user_role set user_id=? where id=?
binding parameter (1:BIGINT) <- [27]
binding parameter (2:BIGINT) <- [null]

I'm expecting inserts with the rolename included. The user and user_role tables currently only have 1 and 2 rows in them respectively. There should be a new user record (there is), and 2 new user_role records with generated ids, and a user_id matching the new user.

I'd better use private User user; instead of private Long userId; in the UserRole table, then add mappedBy="user" in your @OneToMany (and remove @JoinColumn). Anyway if a user can have multiple roles, and a role can be associated to multiple users, you need a @ManyToMany.

Fully agree with @Yann39. Also when using bidirectional relations it may not be sufficient to only add the roles to your User but to set the user on the UserRole objects.

Thanks Yann39, I did try that, but still nothing was inserted into user_role. The trace didn't even show inserts or updates to user_role.
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
private List<UserRole> userRoles;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;

At this point, I'm leaning toward persisting UserRole separately from User. Basically wrapping the save and delete methods for User to also save/delete records in the  user_role table

With the cascadeType attribute it should work. I posted an answer to explain what I meant as it is too long for a comment. Let me know if this meets your needs.

Thank you @Yann39! cascadeType is what I was missing. And just FYI, I was going for something super simple, and I only needed a role name (user can have multiple roles) so user_role is essentially a bridge table just without a role table on the other side. So, no, not deleting a role when the user is deleted, just the user-role association.

If a role is unique for each user (so basically you want to delete the role when you delete a user), just use a bidirectional One-To-Many association :
(sound strange to me but it seems this is what you are trying to do) :
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String rolename;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}

Then to assign a role :
final UserRole roleAdmin = new UserRole();
roleAdmin.setRoleName("ADMIN");

final User user = new User();
user.setUsername("user1");
user.setPassword("xxxxx");
user.getUserRoles.add(roleAdmin);

roleAdmin.setUser(user);

userService.save(user);

If a user can have multiple roles, and a role can be associated to multiples users (which seems more correct to me), then use a Many-To-Many association :
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String rolename;

}

This will generate a user_roles table with user_id and roles_id as composite primary key (you can customize table/column names using @JoinTable annotation in addition to @ManyToMany).
You can also add a @ManyToMany to the Role entity if you need bidirectional Many-To-Many.
Then to assign a role :
final Role roleAdmin = roleService.getByName("ADMIN");

final User user = new User();
user.setUsername("user1");
user.setPassword("xxxxx");
user.getRoles.add(roleAdmin);

userService.save(user);

If you need additional columns in your association table (user_role), then you have to define your association table explicitely and use 2 bidirectional One-To-Many associations :
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String rolename;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(name="role_id")
    private Role role;

    private boolean deserveThisRole;

}

Here you will end up with a user_role table, with user_id and role_id as foreign keys, and an additional column deserve_this_role.
